# Saved .avi video by gstreamer is played too fast in the videoplayers

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer, video-processing, gstreamer-1.0

I save .avi video from the camera, using gstreamer-1.0. Then I try to play this video in VLC player, but it plays too fast.

For example, I recorded video, during 20 seconds, but VLS plays it for 7 seconds.

the gstreamer's script for playing works fine.

Script for recording the video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! video/x-bayer,format=grbg,depth=8,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! bayer2rgbneon ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! avimux ! filesink location=/mnt/video/a.avi
```

Script for playback:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/mnt/video/a.avi ! avidemux ! video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoscale ! kmssink driver-name=imx-drm force-modesetting=false can-scale=false sync=false
```

This solution is based on the phyBOARD-Nunki.

Comment: **(1)** Please provide a testable 20 second video clip that shows this problem. Either you've got saved enough frames (in output file) to show only 7 seconds (_ie:_ your device or script manages to encode a frame every 2.8 seconds). **(2)** Does the 7 seconds look like it skips a lot of frames or is it really every frame just played faster? Also in VLC, under media information, what does it think the video frame rate is?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
It seems that my camera cannot give me 30fps. looks like it has just 8 frames per second.
In VLC I have 30 fps. I guess video is just compressed from 8 fps and 20 sec length to 7 seconds of 30 fps video.
Also I have tried to change the container. I used matroska and save .mkv video file. In VLC it works fine, but has just 8fps

Comment: One more thing. I tried to use 'vidoerate'. The length of video is become good. But a lot of copied frames were appeared. I guess 'videorate' copied the absent frames to fill the video with a necessary amount of frames to reach the 30 fps value

Comment: Got a product link to your camera model/brand? Maybe there's settings to record at 30 fps (or is it some security CCTV cam, hence the low fps?). If 8 fps is the camera ability then you'll have to change your camera hardware cos software 
/ code alone cannot help this issue.

Comment: [Doc](https://www.phytec.eu/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/Manuals/L-748e.pdf) here is the link to the documentation. My cam is in chapter **4.6VM-011 – phyCAM-P camera module** . Colour one. Regarding to the document cam can give me 30fps in fullHD

Comment: Also I tried to use two almost similar pipelines. The difference is just in resolution. I used the `width=800,height=480,framerate=30/1` settings and it worked fine. When I try to increase it to fullHD `width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1` I have a trouble, described in topic.

Comment: Here is the pipeline:
`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! video/x-bayer,format=grbg,depth=8,width=800,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! bayer2rgbneon ! video/x-raw,format=RGBA,width=800,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=800,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,width=800,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! avimux ! filesink location=/mnt/video/a.avi`

Comment: The PDF says cam gives 15 fps at full HD (1080p) or else up to 60 fps at 720p. You could try capturing 30fps at `width=1280,height=720`. If that fails to reach 30 fps, maybe also try an alternative software like FFmpeg instead of GStreamer. FFmpeg can run as terminal tool and **might have** a faster video encoder.

Comment: But on the page 137 there is a pic with info "1920x1080 FullHD 31 max Framerate...". So I guess the cam can give me 30fps. Or I don't understand something xD
Anyway, I will try to capture `width=1280,height=720`

Comment: I was looking at page 131. Also page 137 says a `window` mode is involved for 30 fps at FullHD. Does this `window` stuff mean anything to you? You see any options to set a window (rectangle) for sampling a smaller area of real-world (lens) input?

Comment: Even in `width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1` the video is too fast also :(

Comment: Also. One more point. When I stream the video on the device - it looks like 30 fps video. Is it possible to lose the frames during encoding or any other processing actions?

Comment: Script for streaming `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! video/x-bayer,format=grbg,depth=8,width=1920,height=1080 ! bayer2rgbneon ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1920,height=1080 ! queue ! kmssink driver-name=imx-drm force-modesetting=false can-scale=false sync=false`

Comment: Yes it's possible to lose frames due to either a slow hardware or software. That's why I say try FFmpeg. It has own custom-built encoders. I don't use Linux so can't help with correct download links. Anyways it'll take a day to get used to it but worth it.. It's the best free encoding tool (even used by Youtube as encoder)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help very much! Unfortunately I have to use gstreamer. It's a requirement from customer for the moment

Comment: Verify if this package is installed https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/60695/, in this package the hardware encoder is included.

Comment: @ZxCvBnM, I tried to install it, but it required imx-codecs. I found them into meta-freescale layer. But the complete image has a kernel panic. Tech support answered me, that gstreamer-imx is not supported for 18+ BSP version of their product.

Comment: Hm and manual compiling https://github.com/Freescale/gstreamer-imx/, would that be possible? This way you can use imxvpuenc_h264.

Comment: @ZxCvBnM I will try it, but I am afraid that the gst-imx (compiled manually) will request the same imx-codecs which is absent in the phytec-based build.

Answer (score 0):

The v4l2h264enc is software-based, and it is too slow for the board. The solution is using some hardware-based software like imx encoders, ets.